# Deploying Apps to IPhone without Dev Licence

Tags: iphone, deployment, licensing

Ive applied for the IPhone App developer license over a week ago but still havent heard anything back from apple as of yet.

Im quite deep into the development of my application and am wondering if there is a way i can deploy it to a device for testing in the meantime (while waiting for apple to get back to me)?

I cant jailbreak the phone because its not mine.

Also, does anybody know the average time it takes for apple to "contact your legal representative" and approve the application process?

Thanks

Comment: it took about 2 months for my developer account to the setup

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you jailbreak, no, you will have to wait for a certificate to deploy a signed app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to load apps

Maybe one of your friends has a dev certificate?

I believe the apple process takes a bit over a week - at least that was the case for my UK based Ltd company.

Personal (non-company) applications are quicker; I believe these usually complete within 24 hours.